# Get Automation Runbook Webhook URL

Tags: powershell, azure-automation, azure-runbook, azure-webhooks

I want to retrieve existing Runbook webhook url using powershell script.

I have some existing webhook's which URL I need to retrieve, as given in below image:
[image]

How can we get the URL using Powershell commandlet?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have tried to pulling the webhook url using the 'Get-AzAutomationWebhook' cmdlet this cmdlet is executing successfully but it is showing the webhook url property as null as shown in below.

[image]

Based on the [Azure documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-webhooks#webhook-properties), we cannot pull the webhook url using PowerShell. The URL contains a security token that allows a third-party system to invoke the runbook with no further authentication. For this reason, you should treat the URL like a password. For security reasons, you can only view the URL in the Azure portal when creating the webhook. Note the URL in a secure location for future use.